# Index Match in excel userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have my userform which contain 2 textbox for the target value and the actual value.

TextBox1 will be my target value while TextBox2 will be my actual value.

When the actual value is being key in, the userform will look into the worksheet "Target" and check whether is there any amount need to top up to reach the target value or not.

Here will be my data inside my "Target" worksheet:
[image]

Cell G1:S1 will be my target value while F2:F19 will be my actual value.
If textbox2(actual value) equal to 20A and my textbox1(target value) is 5S,
When go to the next field, textbox3 to fill in others data, it will show a pop up message to alert user to add 50ml conpac in order to reach the target value.

I have been research through webpage but seem like index match does not help in this condition. Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you create the following named ranges: G1:S1 named "Target_Value", F2:F19 named "Actual_Value" and G2:S19 named "Additions" then:

```
=INDEX(Additions,MATCH("20A",Actual_Value,0),MATCH("5S",Target_Value,0))
```

Will return 50. You can put this in a cell somewhere or modify it to work in VBA (using Application.Worksheetfunctions)

Comment: Hi, I have try to set it into the code but it show runtime error 1004: unable to get the match property of the worksheet function class.
Here will be my code:
Private Sub ComboBox6_Change()
myrange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index("Target!Additions", Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(TextBox2.Value, "Target!Actual", 0), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(TextBox1.Value, "Target!Target", 0))
MsgBox myrange

End Sub

Comment: Replace "Target!Additions" by Range("Target!Additions") or perhaps Range("Target!Additions").Value, etc. for Actual and Target. Alternatively, declare a variable, Additions, of type Range and include the line Set Additions = Range("Target!Additions") and use the variable